# Streamlit controlling sidebar title

Tags: python, streamlit

I have a streamlit app with multiple pages which I run from `minimal_example.py`

This is the file content -

```
import streamlit as st

def main():

    page_config = st.set_page_config(
        page_title="my demo",
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The pages folder contains a few other files. It automatically creates a sidebar where the title is the name of the file (see attached image). Is there a way to control it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a markdown link can do the trick:

```py
st.sidebar.title("Folder visualizer")
st.sidebar.markdown(f"[dir1]({filelist[0]})")
```

This way you can put the name you want (here "dir1") and still point to the file or directory needed. Here is what is obtained:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I looked for something more native that would add all the files under `/pages` as once and I can control the title